# How to run shell command from joomla component

Tags: joomla

I'm writing a component in Joomla 3 and want to save the database periodically (eg after a user updates something). I'd like to therefore run *mysqldump* using *shell_exec* (or similar) but I can't get this to work. I suspect it's a permissions issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve this...

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You could make a plugin that runs in response to a save event.  But you could also just make a cron job that does a back up or you could use the Joomla API to run a dump, or you could use something like Akeeba on a very short schedule.  Joomla is a web application so you can just run a shell script from it, that would be scary if possible. Think more web-like and I think that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Your little question inspired us to write a post on how to run SSH commands from Joomla. You can find it here: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-we-ran-an-ssh-command-from-joomla

The post is how we created a secure script that will unblock blocked IPs in CSF - but, the nice thing about it, it provides very clear instructions on how to run ssh commands from a Joomla extension (which is what you essentially need).

I really hope you enjoy this post and that it works for you. If it doesn't, then please provide feedback and we can help!